# Polymorphic constraint

Tags: haskell, types

I have some contrived type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data T a = T a deriving (Functor)
```

... and that type is the instance of some contrived class:

```
class C t where
    toInt :: t -> Int

instance C (T a) where
    toInt _ = 0
```

How can I express in a function constraint that `T a` is an instance of some class for all `a`?

For example, consider the following function:

```
f t = toInt $ fmap Left t
```

Intuitively, I would expect the above function to work since `toInt` works on `T a` for all `a`, but I cannot express that in the type.  This does not work:

```
f :: (Functor t, C (t a)) => t a -> Int
```

... because when we apply `fmap` the type has become `Either a b`.  I can't fix this using:

```
f :: (Functor t, C (t (Either a b))) => t a -> Int
```

... because `b` does not represent a universally quantified variable.  Nor can I say:

```
f :: (Functor t, C (t x)) => t a -> Int
```

... or use `forall x` to suggest that the constraint is valid for all `x`.

So my question is if there is a way to say that a constraint is polymorphic over some of its type variables.

Comment: I assume that something like `class C t where toInt :: t a -> Int` won't work, and you need `C` to be of kind `* -> Constraint`? Would kind polymorphism help here?

Comment: @C.A.McCann The concrete type constructor I have in mind is `Proxy` from `pipes` and the concrete class is `Monad`.  I'm type-classing utility functions for proxy-like types, which is why the constraint is there.  Following your suggestion, I'd then define a `MonadP` class specialized to the shape of the `Proxy` type constructor and use that as a constraint instead.  The disadvantage is that if users wanted to write proxy utility functions polymorphic in the proxy-like type, they'd have to rebind do notation to use `MonadP` instead.

Comment: You can't do it directly, but it's possible to simulate, as in Roman's answer. Here's the relevant GHC ticket: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2893

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [constraints](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints) package:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts, ConstraintKinds, DeriveFunctor, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Constraint
import Data.Constraint.Forall

data T a = T a deriving (Functor)

class C t where
    toInt :: t -> Int

instance C (T a) where
    toInt _ = 0

f :: ForallF C T => T a -> Int
f t = (toInt $ fmap Left t) \\ (instF :: ForallF C T :- C (T (Either a b)))
```

Comment: It's also worth looking at the source of that `ForallF`, if only to admire how simple/ugly/terrifying the idea behind it is :)

Comment: @copumpkin: I actually have a question about that — http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728159/how-does-the-constraints-package-work

Comment: We now have [`-XQuantifiedConstraints`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/quantified_constraints.html)