# How does the constraints package work?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, logic

The idea behind [Data.Constraint.Forall](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/constraints/0.3.2/doc/html/src/Data-Constraint-Forall.html), as I understand it, is to use coercion in the implementation, but ensure safety using the type system. I have two questions regarding the latter.

1. Why do we need two skolem variables — A and B? I would imagine that if a constraint is satisfied by an «unknown» type, then it is polymorphic. How does the second type give more safety?
2. Why are these types called skolem variables? I thought that skolemnization is used to remove existential quantification, and here we see universal quantification. Is there a sign-flipping somewhere which I missed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible with an MPTC and functional dependency to identify the Skolem when it is a single variable, by using a constraint parameterized on a constraint. The trick I used to do that doesn't work when there are two.

From the perspective of code written outside of this module, the variables *are* Skolemized. They are effectively a 'fresh' type constructor.

But given that you can't refer explicitly to these types outside of the module since they aren't exported, any instance that covers these Skolems has to be universally quantified.

This is how I upgrade from an existential to a universal. The 'sign flip' comes from their unexported nature, not technically from their role as Skolems.

Comment: Thanks. Could you show the trick you're talking about? Also, do you have a proof (or a convincing argument) that two variables are enough?

Comment: I'll see if I can dig it up. It was just a quick example I banged out back when I wrote the code in question. The "convincing argument" is just that the hack I came up with didn't work, and that any sketch I could come up with that might see through it was going to be way too much work to test. It may well be possible with sufficient Oleggery to work around the two variable solution, but you'll almost certainly need some pretty heavy machinery to do it. ;)

Comment: Off the cuff, the simplest example came down to using a class and a fundep. Remember you can have `class Foo a b | a -> b, b -> a`, then if you 'quantify' over the second argument of `Foo a a` is not parametric in its second argument, even though you can instantiate that second argument with the Skolem `A`. But when you go to use two types, the fundep trick no longer works, because now the requirement for both `(Foo A A, Foo A B)` defeats the fundep.

Comment: And so two variables is enough to defeat this fairly obvious avenue of attack. I do not have a proof that this is the only attack vector, though. It may well be possible to construct a class that takes a constraint as its argument, and another argument, and has some complicated fundep chain between them that somehow exposes just enough information to allow you to discriminate against the Skolem. However, it is likely that such a construction would require at least overlapping/incoherent instances.